# how to join tables in yii2

Tags: join, gridview, yii2

I have two tables in my project companies and contacts.
companies table contents company id, name, website etc.
contacts contents first name ,last name, email of company employees.

when I click on company name I should get employee contacts of that company.
like "select * from contacts where company id = $id"

companies/index.php

```
$gridColumns = [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
                    'name', // onclick of name ,how to open contacts table containing that 'name'
                    'company_mail',
                ];

 echo GridView::widget([
                'tableOptions' => ['id' => 'companies_grid_table',
                'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'],
                'id'=> 'companies_grid_display',
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'columns' => $gridColumns,
            ]);
```

this is companies table when click on name of company the other table named "contact" should get open
[image]

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to ask? if you want to click on the company name and list the contacts submit the company `id` `onclick` to another page/action and then call a view with `gridview` same like this and list the contacts on that separate page for this company, you should go through the documentation before start asking questions

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam see the edits ..you may understand what I am asking for..

Comment: Have you trying something before asking? Here you can find some help but nobody develops for you. So first try to code a solution and then, if you get some errors, try to ask. For relations between tables look at this  [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/780/drills-search-by-a-has_many-relation-in-yii-2-0/)

Answer (score 0):

if I understood... try this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [
    [
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value' => function ($data) {
            return Html::a($data->name, ['/custom-url/contacts', 'ContactSearch[company_id]' => $model->id]);
        },
 ]]]); ?>
```